# Wordpress: Featured image -> media library : increase media number

Tags: wordpress

Is there a way in Wordpress to increase the number of media items shown in featured image -> media library.
Currently it is limited to 4 media item per page... How can I increase the number of item being displayed per page ?

Answer (score 0):

By default the library list 20 items per page, so seems like you already have a customization in place. Maybe you can look on the functions.php file of your theme or a plugin added to the site.